# Using stateless EJB beans in an Entity Bean

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

Obviously using stateless EJB beans in an entity bean smells, but please consider a scenario as follows and tell me if you know of a better solution:

1. I have an `InvoiceTemplate` Entity Bean with field `NextInvoiceDate`
2. Generating `NextInvoiceDate` is a complex procedure and should be performed outside of the `InvoiceTemplate` class
3. `NextInvoiceDate` should be updated each time `InvoiceTemplate` is stored to the db

For now I have logic regarding the generation of `NextInvoiceDate` in `@PrePersist` `@PreUpdate` methon in `InvoiceTemplate` entity bean. The logic is getting more and more complicated and I want to move it outside of the `InvoiceTemplate` entity bean. It looks to me that there should be a service to calculate `NextInvoiceDate`. But then is it right to invoke this service from the inside of `InvoiceTemplate`?

Comment: is it an entity-bean (EJB 2.0) or a JPA entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't such a smell - it is a lean towards domain-driven design.

I don't know of any way to do this automatically, but you can:

- in the session beans where you handle your `Invoicetemplate`, inject the helper bean that has the logic to calculate the next date
- create a private field with a setter on the entity, and before you start using it call `entity.setNextDateHelper(..)`

You can also check whether [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) doesn't offer some EJB options so that you can inject the EJB whenever an entity of a given type (`InvoiceTemplate`) is created. AspectJ works like that with spring beans, I don't know whether there are such options for EJB.

Comment: Well said. +1 just for the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need anything as complicated as a service or EJB?  Can you just write a static method (possibly on a utility class) to hold the logic?  Normally I'm pretty biased against this sort of thing, but if all you've got is some complex logic that doesn't require any DB interaction or a lot of object collaboration, it may be the cleanest approach.

Comment: Testing would be hurt in this way.

Comment: Well, what if it _does_ require DB interaction and a lot of object collaboration?

Comment: If it does, then you're probably back to a service or EJB again, so you can participate in transactions or share context.  Which brings you back to timing issues, coordination and dependencies.